# About convergence a.s of iid random variable sequence

Tags: probability, probability-theory, convergence-divergence, solution-verification

$$
\mbox{I want to prove that}\quad
\frac{\max\left\{X_1,\ldots,X_n\right\}}{n} \to 0
$$
almost sure
$\iff E\left\lvert X_{1}\right\rvert < \infty$ when $\left\lbrace X_{n}\right\rbrace_{n}$ are random independent and identically distributed variables. I could show the $\Leftarrow$ implication but have no idea for the other.

Comment: It may help to show your proof for the one implication so that answers can show how to use similar reasoning to obtain the other.

Comment: I used that $P(\frac{max(X_1,...,X_n)}{n} \geq \varepsilon$ if $n \geq n_0) = P(max(X_1,...,X_n) \geq \varepsilon n) \leq \frac{E\lvert X_1 \rvert}{n \varepsilon} \to 0$ by Chebyshev's inequality if $E \lvert X_1 \rvert < \infty$

Answer (score 0):

The positivity condition is missing. If $X_n$ can be negative, then any sequence of real negative random variables satisfies the first claim while the second claim does not always hold.
Given the positivy of $(X_n)$, the other direction can be proven as follows:

$\mathbb{E}( |X_1| ) = +\infty \iff \sum_{n \ge 1} \mathbb{P}(|X_n| \ge n) = +\infty \underbrace{\iff}_{\text{ Borel Cantelli}}  1= \mathbb{P}( \limsup \frac{|X_n|}{n} \ge 1) \iff \limsup \frac{|X_n|}{n} \ge 1 \text{ a.s} $
From which, we imply the other direction.